# Checkbox values are not in a commaseparated string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I have form similar to this:

```
<form action="MyForm.htm" method="GET">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="cb1" name="xxx"/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="cb2" name="xxx"/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="cb3" name="xxx"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!"/>
</form>
```

Checking the checkboxes and submitting the form results in this url:

```
/MyForm.htm?xxx=1&xxx=2&xxx=3
```

Since the checkboxes all have the same `name` I was expecting this:

```
/MyForm.htm?xxx=1,2,3
```

Am I missing something? Or is the behaviour I'm seeing in fact correct? In that case: Didn't it use to be the way I was expecting??

Comment: Note that [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-content-type) does not meet your expectations... "The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document. The name is separated from the value by `=' and name/value pairs are separated from each other by `&'."

Answer (score 0):

```
    function cal()
    {
      var res="";
      var box = document.getElementsByName('xxx');
      for(var i=0;i<box.length;i++)
      {
      if(box[i].checked)
      {
        res+= box[i].value;
        if(box[i+1])
        {
           res+=",";
        }
      } 
      }

      var form = document.getElementById('yourform');
      var url = "whateverMypage.php?xxx="+res;
      form.setAttribute('action',url);

    }
```

pass `res` as parameter, it will contain all these checked item values

Comment: how will you pass the res, in the form submit ?

Comment: you can pass it hidden input field

Answer (score 0):

That is simply how form data is sent (and it has always been that way). The values are sent as separate key-value pairs as they are from separate fields, and to be possible to distinguish from:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1,2,3" name="xxx"/>
```

If you want to make a single comma separated value from the separate values, you have to change the data before the form is sent, for example by putting the values in a hidden input.